# Detecting change in users/groups on web

Tags: event-receivers, spweb, events, access-rights

I want to execute some code when the users/groups with access to a web changes (addition and removal of users/groups). What are my options?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are using SP 2013, you can `SPSecurityEventReceiver`. A good resource on this is: http://www.timferro.com/wordpress/archives/737.

Excerpts:

> [This Server Side and Remote Event Receiver] Provides methods [in 5 main categories: 1. Group Events, 2. User Events, 3. Inheritance Events, 4. Role Assignment Events, and 5. Role Definition Events] to trap events [Adding/Added/Updating/Updated/Deleting/Deleted/Breaking/Broken/Reset/Resetting] that are raised [at the Site Collection or Site level] for security.

Comment: Cool that is exactly what I am looking for. Will this work as remote eventreceiver too?

Comment: I think so. Haven't tried it but as mentioned in the link I posted, I assume it will work.